# Undefined function when extends class in nodejs typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

i want to access to class function when wxtends that class in typescript .

this is my class `BaseController :`

```
   "use strict";

import { validationResult } from "express-validator";
import applyBind from 'auto-bind';

export class ValidationResult {
    haveError: boolean;
    errorMessage: string[];

    constructor(haveError: boolean, errorMessage: string[]) { }
}

export default class BaseCotnroller {

    constructor() {
        applyBind.bind(this);
    }

   static async ValidationAction(req, res): Promise<ValidationResult> {
        const result = await validationResult(req);
        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            let errors = result.array();
            let message = [];
            errors.forEach((element) => {
                message.push(element.msg);
            });
            return new ValidationResult(true, message);
        }
        return new ValidationResult(false, null);
    }

}
```

and then extends the `BaseController :`

```
   import BaseCotnroller from './BaseController';


export default class PermissionController extends BaseCotnroller {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    /*** Create Permission ****/
    static async CreatePermission(req, res, next) {
            let validationData = await this.ValidationAction(req, res); 
            if (!validationData.haveError) {
                PermissionRepository.CreatePermission(req)
                    .then(() => {
                        this.Ok(res);
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        return this.BadRerquest(res, error);
                    });
            } else {
                return this.BadRerquest(res, validationData.errorMessage);
            }   
    }


}
```

but it show me this error :

> error TypeError: Cannot read property 'ValidationAction' of undefined
> at F:\Projects\Nodejs\Travel Budy\src\http\controller\PermissionController.ts:20:45
> at Generator.next ()
> at F:\Projects\Nodejs\Travel Budy\src\http\controller\PermissionController.ts:8:71
> at new Promise ()
> at __awaiter (F:\Projects\Nodejs\Travel Budy\src\http\controller\PermissionController.ts:4:12)
> at CreatePermission (F:\Projects\Nodejs\Travel Budy\src\http\controller\PermissionController.ts:24:16)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\Projects\Nodejs\Travel Budy\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (F:\Projects\Nodejs\Travel Budy\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch (F:\Projects\Nodejs\Travel Budy\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\Projects\Nodejs\Travel Budy\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at F:\Projects\Nodejs\Travel Budy\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
> at Function.process_params (F:\Projects\Nodejs\Travel Budy\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
> at next (F:\Projects\Nodejs\Travel Budy\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
> at Function.handle (F:\Projects\Nodejs\Travel Budy\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
> at router (F:\Projects\Nodejs\Travel Budy\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\Projects\Nodejs\Travel Budy\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

**now whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?**

Comment: How are you calling that static `CreatePermission` method?

Comment: i calling that by this : `import permission from './../../http/controller/PermissionController';
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/create', permission.CreatePermission)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @JaredSmith this is not worked for me man

Comment: That's just the auto-generated comment when somebody links your question as a duplicate of an existing one. You can't pass a method as a callback without binding it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind `CreatePermission` method to `permission` class when registering the route handler:

```
router.post('/create', permission.CreatePermission.bind(permission));
```

Alternatively, you can change `static` methods to regular ones, create a PermissionController instance and use it for route handling:

```
import PermissionController from './../../http/controller/PermissionController';
const permission = new PermissionController()
const router = express.Router();  
router.post('/create', permission.CreatePermission)
```

Comment: it worked but i think this is not good way . i using this `constructor() {
        applyBind.bind(this);
    }` but its not worked. why ?

Comment: `applyBind.bind(this);` does not work for `static` methods because `this` inside the `constructor` refers to the concrete instance while `this` inside static methods refers to the class itself.

Comment: if i can remove the static , it not show me that function . why ?

Comment: Make sure that you create an instance and use it when registering the route handler. I have updated the answer respectively.